# User input to call function always ends with process 0

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to make a program which shows an exp or log function depending on what the user wants to see. So if the user wants to have exp fun, then he writes 1. If log fun, then 2.

The problem is that after inputting the program always ends with "Process finished with exit code 0" and it shows no functions.

What can be the solution?

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class the_process(object):
 def logfun(self):
    a = 2
    q = 0
    x = np.linspace(-2, 4, 100)
    y = np.log(a ** (np.add(x, q)))

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.ylabel('$\log(x)$')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

def expfun(self):
    a = 2
    q = 0
    x = np.linspace(-2, 4, 100)
    y = np.add(np.power(a, x), q)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.ylabel('$\exp(x)$')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

def __init__(self):
    self.a = input(
        "Which function do you want to use? \n\n 1) The first one. \n\n 2) The second one. \n\n Please enter the corresponding number and hit enter >>>>> ")

    if self.a == 1:
        self.expfun()
    elif self.a == 2:
        self.logfun()


a = the_process();
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation in your example is wrong. `expfun()` and `__init__()` are not indented. Also, [`input()` returns a string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), so you should cast it to int to compare it in your `if`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class the_process(object):
    def logfun(self):
        a = 2
        q = 0
        x = np.linspace(-2, 4, 100)
        y = np.log(a ** (np.add(x, q)))

        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.ylabel('$\log(x)$')
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()

    def expfun(self):
        a = 2
        q = 0
        x = np.linspace(-2, 4, 100)
        y = np.add(np.power(a, x), q)

        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.ylabel('$\exp(x)$')
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()


    def __init__(self):
        self.a = int(input(
            "Which function do you want to use? \n\n 1) The first one. \n\n 2) The second one. \n\n Please enter the corresponding number and hit enter >>>>> "))

        if self.a == 1:
            self.expfun()
        elif self.a == 2:
            self.logfun()


a = the_process()
```

Finally, in my opinion, your problem shouldn't be structured as a class, so you could consider this one instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class TheProcess(object):
    def log_fun(self):
        a = 2
        q = 0
        x = np.linspace(-2, 4, 100)
        y = np.log(a ** (np.add(x, q)))

        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.ylabel("$\log(x)$")
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()

    def exp_fun(self):
        a = 2
        q = 0
        x = np.linspace(-2, 4, 100)
        y = np.add(np.power(a, x), q)

        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.ylabel("$\exp(x)$")
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()


chosen_option = int(
    input(
        "Which function do you want to use? \n\n 1) The first one. \n\n 2) The second one. \n\n Please enter the corresponding number and hit enter >>>>> "
    )
)
my_process = TheProcess()
if chosen_option == 1:
    my_process.exp_fun()
elif chosen_option == 2:
    my_process.log_fun()
else:
    print("Exiting...")
```